# Does a constant speed prop deliver max speed at max manifold pressure and max RPM?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, piston-engine, constant-speed-propeller

I was reading a discussion in flight simulator forum and I found this statement:

> Ignoring the issue of engine overheating, max MAP and max RPM is the
> best thing for max speed

Do you agree with that?
Assuming a Constant Speed Propeller.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum speed, you need maximum power from your engine. This means running it at its maximum rated RPM with the throttle wide open, and maximum manifold boost pressure for a supercharged engine. The prop governor will then adjust the prop pitch to put the biggest possible load on the engine at that RPM.